# Append sum of rows and columns to matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have (n,n) numpy array. I want to append a column vector where each element in it is the sum of the corresponding rows. I also append a row vector to the end of the matrix which is a sum of the corresponding columns. However, appending these 1D arrays is not compatible from a dimensional stand point. I want to append these, but have a matrix where the point (-1,-1) is the sum of either the last row or column (as they are equal).

Example;

```
x = np.random.randint(5, size=(4, 4))
columns = np.sum(x,axis=1)
rows = np.sum(np.transpose(x),axis=1)
```

Comment: Try appending the sums of rows as a column first, to create an `(n, n+1)`-dimensional array, _then_ append the sums of the columns as a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like that:
First let's generate some matrix `a`

```
n=5
k=4
a=np.zeros([n,k])
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(k):
        a[i][j]=i+2*j
```

Then run the following commands.
This adds the row:

```
a=np.append(a,[np.sum(a,axis=0)],axis=0)
```

This calculates the column

```
col=np.array([np.sum(a,axis=1)])
```

Finally we add the column

```
a=np.concatenate((a,col.T),axis=1)
print(a)
```

Note that this takes care of the (-1,-1)  entry as well.